# Python Pandas Questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

Hello I am using python version 3 to retrieve data from a building automation system thru RESTapi query. This returns a lot of data, but I dont think its in pandas series format... I also attached a snip of the python shell output. Ultimately what I am trying to do a create a pandas series to do some simple math but Im doing something wrong!

```
hwr = session.find_entity(filter_expr='secondaryhwr').result
hwr_df = session.his_read_frame(hwr, rng= '2017-05-01,2017-07-25').result

print(hwr_df.tail())
print(hwr_df.head())
print(hwr_df.describe())

print(type(hwr_df))
print(hwr_df.columns)
print(type(hwr_df.index))
```

[Python Shell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnM2L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a DataFrame is being returned. You can convert this to a Series by doing:

```
hwr_df = pd.Series(hwr_df[hwr_df.columns[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the tip, that totally worked...! Please let me know if I should mark this as 'resolved' if stackoverflow has this requirement... Have a great day!